# Table to Excel For loop keeps producing lock file in directory using ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have the following code that I developed to convert my `.dbf` zonal statistics outputs into `.xls` using arcpy. I am trying to run the loop using three files as a test;
`ppt_07223000_190001.dbf`, `ppt_07223000_190002.dbf` and `ppt_07223000_190001.dbf`

```
import arcpy
import os
import glob
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
import numpy as np

####################
# Set the workspace#
####################

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\Prism\tdmean files\tdmean_Excel'

############################
### Search for dbf files ###
############################

dbf_filenames = sorted(glob.glob("*.dbf"))

# pieces = 10
# new_arrays = np.array_split(dbf_filenames, pieces)

for dbf in dbf_filenames:
    # print(dbf)
    basefilename = os.path.basename(dbf)
    # print(basefilename)
    CleanBaseStr = os.path.splitext(basefilename)[0]
    field_name = "Year_Month"
    field_type = "DOUBLE"

    # arcpy.management.DeleteField(dbf, field_name)
    arcpy.management.AddField(dbf, field_name, field_type, field_length = 6)

    field = ["Year_Month"]
    yearmonth = os.path.splitext(basefilename)[0][13:21]

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dbf, field) as cursor:
            try:
                for row in cursor:

                    row[0] = yearmonth
                    cursor.updateRow(row)

                    ### Execute table to excel
                    out_xls = CleanBaseStr + ".xls"
                    print(f"{out_xls} : {row}")
                    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(dbf, out_xls)
            except:
                continue
```

Ideally the output should look something like this.
[image: Excel Output]

However, the issue arises in the directory. For some reason, the loop gets stuck after the first run and gets locked there.

```
# ppt_07223000_190001.xls : ['190001']
```

There is no error produced which makes it a bit more confusing.
[image: locked files]

However, when changing the `arcpy.env.workspace` to an external workspace, the script runs as shown by this print statement, but no excel output is produced.

```
# ppt_07223000_190001.xls : ['190001']
# ppt_07223000_190002.xls : ['190002']
# ppt_07223000_190003.xls : ['190003']
```

Comment: Shouldn't the table to Excel line be outside of your update cursor loop or are you creating an excel doc for each record in each dbf table?

Comment: @Howeitzer Each dbf table is only 1 row long as I am trying to extract yearly data for the same shape file. So what I am trying to do is convert each dbf table individually into a separate excel doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update cursor will lock the dbf file as you are inside it. One option is to just keep track of what you want to save out as and then loop through it at the end. Something like this.

```
    out_files = []    
    for dbf in dbf_filenames:
        .....
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dbf, field) as cursor:
                try:
                    for row in cursor:
    
                        row[0] = yearmonth
                        cursor.updateRow(row)
    
                        ### Execute table to excel
                        out_xls = CleanBaseStr + ".xls"
                        print(f"{out_xls} : {row}")
                        out_files.append([dbf, out_xls])
                except:
                    continue

    for dbf,out_xls in out_files:
        arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(dbf, out_xls)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but even after doing this the `.dbf` file still produces a lock file. The loop gets stuck at `ppt_07223000_190001.xlsx`

Comment: Also, when I try to set the `arcpy.env.workspace` to an external workspace, I get the error
`OSError: "ppt_07223000_190001.dbf" does not exist`

Comment: It looks like the TableToExcel does not release the lock before proceeding to the next dbf file, and you are using the same dbf file repeatedly. You could try importing time, and using time.sleep(number of seconds) in order to pause and let arcpy finish the conversion and releasing the dbf file. You could also copy your dbf file into a pandas dataframe in memory and save it out using to_xlsx.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with this problem, I had to change the code where I converted the `.dbf` files to a `pandas.dataframe()` and then managed to convert that output to separate excel files. It works just like I wanted it to.